# Restarting a service in android does get my global variables

Tags: android, android-activity

My application should check to see if an alarm needs to go off (MP3 is played) when it starts, after that it should check every 5 minutes.

If the stop button is pressed the timer should then be 1 hour, I was having a problem where the alarm would go off again in 5 minutes after the button was pressed the first time(because the background service was already in a wait with the original 5 min timer) I thought a way around this would be to start and stop the service when the button is pressed but I still get the same result, alarm goes off after 5 mins, but after that it has an hour wait.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Main Activity

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {
private Thread thread;
private String CurrentString;
private int MaxCalls;
private int cph;
private int mht;
private String alarm;
private int timer =10000;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private TextView MaxCallstxt,MHTtxt,CPHtxt;
private static final String TAG = "MainScreen";
private Date inTime,outTime,inputTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    registerReceiver(uiUpdated, new IntentFilter("LOCATION_UPDATED"));
    final Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(myIntent);

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainScreen.this, R.raw.rescueme);

    Button SoundButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    SoundButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                //stop or pause your media player mediaPlayer.stop(); or mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                Global g = new Global();
                g.set_timer(3600000);
               stopService(myIntent);
                startService(myIntent);
             }
            return false;
        }
    });


    MaxCallstxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Maxcallstxt);
    CPHtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CPHtxt);
    MHTtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MHTtxt);

};

private BroadcastReceiver uiUpdated= new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date mToday = new Date();
        String ts = tsLong.toString();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
        String curTime = sdf.format(mToday);
        try {

             inputTime = sdf.parse(curTime);
             inTime = sdf.parse("07:00");
             outTime = sdf.parse("23:59");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in formatting " + e.toString());
    }

        String[] separated = intent.getExtras().getString("MaxCalls").split("\\|");
        MaxCalls = Integer.parseInt(separated[0].toString()); // MaxCalls
        cph = Integer.parseInt(separated[1].toString()); // cph
        mht = Integer.parseInt(separated[2].toString()); // mht
        alarm = separated[3].toString(); // Alarm = true/False

        MaxCallstxt.setText("Max Calls : " + MaxCalls);
        MHTtxt.setText("MHT : " + mht);
        CPHtxt.setText("CPH : " + cph);

       // alarm = "True";

        if (alarm.equals("True"))
        {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
            }
            else
            {
                if((inputTime.after(inTime) && inputTime.before(outTime)) || (MaxCalls == 0 && cph== 0 && mht ==0))
                {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }

            }

        }


    }
};

public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // make GET request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

        // receive response  as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

   // } catch (Exception e) {
  //      Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    //} catch (IOException e) {
      //  Log.e("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", e);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    return result;
}

// convert inputstream to String
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Background service

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
MediaPlayer player;
private Thread thread;
private String CurrentString;
private int timer =10000;
private boolean firsttime = true;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

   player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rescueme);
   player.setLooping(false); // Set looping


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    player.stop();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(true)
            {
                try {

                    Global g = new Global();
                    timer=g.get_timer();
                    firsttime=g.get_firsttime();
                    if (firsttime == true)
                    {
                        g.set_firstime(false);
                    }else{
                        Thread.sleep(timer);
                    }



                    CurrentString =GET("http://example.com/example.aspx");
                    Intent i = new Intent("LOCATION_UPDATED");
                    i.putExtra("MaxCalls",CurrentString);
                    sendBroadcast(i);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //REST OF CODE HERE//
            }

        }
    }).start();

    //  player.start();
}

public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // make GET request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

        // receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

        // } catch (Exception e) {
        //      Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        //} catch (IOException e) {
        //  Log.e("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", e);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    return result;
}

// convert inputstream to String
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

}

Global

```
public class  Global extends Application
{
static public int timer;
static public boolean firsttime = true;
public int get_timer() {
    if (timer==0)
    {
     timer = 300000;
    }
    return timer;
}
public void set_timer(int _timer) {
    this.timer = _timer;
}
public boolean get_firsttime() {
    return firsttime;
}
public void set_firstime(boolean _firsttime) {
    this.firsttime = _firsttime;
}
```

Comment: you are doing it in worst possible way (Thread.sleep? really? for timers?) use AlarmManager + SharedPreferences

Comment: I'm pretty new to Android Dev.

I only want the alarm to go off if alarm=true is returned by the httpget.

Is this possible with AlarmManger? I don't want to set certain times for it to go off. More if the values returned by the httpget post are true, which I need to check every 15 mins

Comment: Use AlarmManager to just wake up your service to do something. It can then check the parameters and do whatever is necessary (including doing nothing, setting an alarm to wake itself up again later).